# Фиксация минимальной, возможно нестабильной, версии пакета в gentoo

Tags: gentoo

Установил dev-db/sqldeveloper версии 4.1.3.20.78, но после выполнения команды

```
emerge --update --deep --ask --newuse @world
```

Система предлагает даунгрейд выполнить, что я не хочу.

```
[ebuild    FUD ] dev-db/sqldeveloper-4.0.2.15.21 [4.1.3.20.78]
```

как такое исправить, в каком файле нужно написать, скорее всего

```
>=dev-db/sqldeveloper-4.1.3.20.78
```

?

Comment: в `/etc/portage/package.mask/package.mask` эту строку попробуйте написать. Хотя через него я обычно наоборот фиксирую версии, что бы более новые не ставились. Но что то мне подсказывает, что после этого оно начнет завершаться с ошибкой блокировок зависимостей. Придется копать в сторону того, из за какого пакета оно это хочет. Или может после --sync новую версию посчитали нестабильной и вынесли в ~amd64 (или какая там платформа)

Answer (score 1):

В файл

```
/etc/portage/package.accept_keywords
```

нужно добавить строку

```
=dev-db/sqldeveloper-4.1.3.20.78 ~amd64
```